# AES256 Encryption with CBC and without padding in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, encryption, password-encryption

I have to do the encryption with AES 256 , CBC and without padding . I have an code which do simple AES256 but requirement is different .

I have an JSON string which i need to pass to the server with AES256/CBC/Nopadding.

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: I also need the same thing in one of my app. But I didnt find any solution till now. can anyone help me

Comment: Perhaps this question and answer will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287727/aes256-nsstring-encryption-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can use CommonCrypto to achieve this.
In CCCryptorCreate there is CCOptions parameter, where you should pass 0 (instead of PKCS7Padding constant).